# How could I do this kind of scheduled task in AppEngine Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a form with a text field for entering a number without decimal
places representing an amount of minutes that will have to be added to the current time
and will be inserted into a table named `Alarm`.

When the resulting time comes, my web app must make an insert operation over another table.

For example, if the user enters `20` minutes, and the current time is `22:10`, the result time
will have to be `22:30` and will be inserted into `Alarm` table. So, when the `22:30` arrives, a new insert will have to be made over the another table.

How can I do this on AppEngine using Python?

Comment: I have read this article http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html but I don't know how to apply it to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've said that you're storing the target time in the Alarm table. So, your cron just has to run every minute (or every 5 or 10, depending on the resolution of your alarms) and check if there's an alarm matching the current time, and if so then do the action.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, please correct me if I'm wrong: you suggest I must invoke from my cron to the url with the method handler that 
performs a select over "Alarm" and in that method I check the current time and in case it matches the time stored on "Alarm" table I must do the action, right?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your requirements, you may also want to consider using [Tasks](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview.html) with an [eta](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/tasks.html#Task_eta) or countdown.

If you plan to allow users to cancel the action, you'd need to use some type of no-op marker the task checks for before adding to the "other" table.  Or, make the task check the `Alarm` table before performing the add.

Also, note that the countdown / eta are not precise, they are more like polite requests.  So if your queues are backing up with tasks, your adds will happen after they are supposed to.  (though cron, particularly 1 minute jobs, also periodically suffer timing issues).

The advantage of this method is that you don't have to figure out how to avoid missing work.  Each task represents one add (or a related set of adds).  Also, if a write fails the task will retry, which is nice.

Cron may be a better solution for your particular problem though.

Comment: many thanks Robert. I think the solution given by Daniel Roseman is working properly, so I'll implement 
his suggestion but I'll consider your second opinion in case something start going wrong =)